# Is working at a marijuana dispensary haram?

Tags: money, work, legal

The title says it all, is it permissible to work at a legal marijuana dispensary?  I get a  I work at a place that sells product for both recreational and medicinal consumption.  It's the best job I can find at the moment and the bosses have been super accommodating to me this Ramadan, more so than any bosses I've had previously.  No one is expected to use the product and it's actually against the rules for any workers there to be under the influence of the product on the job.

Answer (score -2):

This is my opinion so take it with a pinch of salt but I think it may be haram because I think of it as a Muslim working in a pub serving alcohol which is also haram.

Comment: If you're not too educated, please don't answer.